# Filtering multiple users with get-aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm new to powershell and have to fetch users from AD based on a list with names. Is there any way to filter from AD using something similar to an in-statement in SQL? (select * from users where name in ('Joe','Bill)?

As for now I fetch users in a foreach loop and add them to an arraylist, but I don't know if this is good practice:

```
function GetUsers()
{
$dummydata = @('Bill','Joe','Sam')
$users = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

foreach($user in $dummydata)
{
 $aduser = get-aduser -f {GivenName -eq $user} -Properties * | select *
  $users.add($aduser) | Out-Null
}

Return ,$users

}
```

Comment: As an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd probably want to put this into a function:

```
$dummydata = @('Bill','Joe','Sam')

$filter = 
[scriptblock]::create(($dummydata| foreach {"(GivenName -eq '$_')"}) -join ' -or ')
Get-ADUser -f $filter
```

Comment: I've never seen the foreach be used inside a filter, usually I use it to run a get-aduser for each user. Could you explain how this works? Not sure what the -join and -or are actually doing.

Comment: @Jessie: The `foreach[-object]` is merely used to construct an array of transformed strings from the array of input strings (embedding them in a simple filter expression each), and `-join` then joins the simple filters with `-or` to form a compound expression.
The resulting single string is passed to `[scriptblock]::Create()`.

Answer (score 5):

[mjolinor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270099/45375) is elegant and works, but **the use of *script blocks* is problematic** for two reasons:

- It is *unnecessary*, because the script block will invariably be converted back to a *string* when it is passed to `Get-ADUser -Filter`.
- More importantly, it **perpetuates the widespread misconception that `Get-ADUser -Filter` accepts PowerShell *script blocks* that support *PowerShell syntax*, which is *not* true**; it is a misconception that leads to frustration sooner or later; in short: **construct your `-Filter` arguments as *strings* to begin with**, and know that these filter strings, **while *resembling* PowerShell syntax, use *AD-provider-specific* syntax**, which is not only much more limited, but behaves subtly differently even with operators of the same name as in PowerShell - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375) for the full story.

Therefore, **use string manipulation to construct your filter**:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter ('Bill', 'Joe', 'Sam' -replace 
                      '^.*', 'GivenName -eq "$&"' -join ' -or ')
```

<sup>For information on the regex-based `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).</sup>

The `-Filter` argument evaluates to the following string literal, which is what the AD provider ultimately sees:

```
GivenName -eq "Bill" -or GivenName -eq "Joe" -or GivenName -eq "Sam"
```

Answer (score 0):

while I agree with [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) in spirit, scriptblocks have the following two advantages over single quoted strings.

1. The value can have single quotes (as in D'Sean) or even double quotes without you escaping the quotes.
2. syntax highlighting.