# Renaming files by reformatting existing filenames - placeholders in replacement strings used with the -replace operator

Tags: file, powershell, replace, rename

I have a few video file like this:
`VideoName_s01e01.mp4` where the season and episodes are variables. I want to add an underscore ("_") between the `s??` and `e??`.

I have been using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for renaming purposes, I have a starting point:

```
GCI $path -filter '*_s??e??*' -rec |  Ren -new { $_.name -replace '_s[0-9][0-9]', '_s[0-9]_[0-9]_' } -passthru
```

This actually renamed my files `VideoName_s[0-9]_e[0-9].mp4`.

Basically, I am looking for the characters `s??e??` I just don't know how to make them variables in the replace section.

I think the best method would be:

1. Find the position of `e??s??` (let's call it X).
2. split the string at `X-3`.
3. concatenate the string with a "`_`" in the middle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Martin Brandl's answer provides an elegant and effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40682779/45375), but it's worth digging deeper:

PowerShell's **[`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)** (`... -replace <search>[, <replace>]`):

- Takes a [*regular expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) as its first operand, `<search>` (the search expression), and invariably matches *globally*, i.e., it replaces *all* matches.

  - `'bar' -replace '[ra]', '@'` -> `'b@@'`
  - If you want to replace a *literal* string, you must either individually `\`-escape any regex metacharacters (e.g. `.`) or use the result from a [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) call:

    - `'bar.none' -replace '\.', '-'`  -> `'bar-none'`
    - `'bar.none' -replace [regex]::Escape('.'), '-'` -> `'bar-none'`
- Specifying a replacement expression, `<replace>`, is *optional*, in which case the *empty string* is substituted for what `<search>` matched, resulting in its effective *removal*.

  - `'bar' -replace '[ra]'` -> `'b'`
- If `<replace>` *is* specified, it supports two forms:

  - **v6.1+** ([PowerShell *Core*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only): A *script block*  (`{ ... }`) as the replacement operand, which offers fully dynamic calculation of the replacement string on a per-match basis:

    - `'Level 41' -replace '\d+', { 1 + $_.Value }` -> `'Level 42'`
  - A *string* containing an expression that can reference what the regular expression captured (and didn't capture) - such as `$&` to refer to what was matched - explained in detail below.

    - `'bar' -replace '[ra]', '{$&}'` -> `'b{a}{r}'`
- `-replace` matches case-*insensitively* (and can also be written as `-ireplace`); to perform case-*sensitive* matching, use the form `-creplace`.

---

**The "replacement language" for referencing regex captures in a string-typed `<replace>` operand is itself *not* a regular expression** - no matching happens there, **only references to the *results* of the regex matching are supported**, via **`$`-prefixed placeholders** that are **not to be confused with *PowerShell* variables**.

- PowerShell's documentation (now) briefly explains the syntax of replacement strings in its conceptual [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) help topic.
- For the full picture, refer to the [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) .NET framework help topic, which is applicable because PowerShell's `-replace` uses the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_) method
  behind the scenes.

For convenience, here are the **references supported in the `<replace>` string** (excerpted from the page linked above, with emphasis and annotations added):

- `$number` (e.g., `$1`) ... Includes the last **substring matched by the capture group that is identified by the `1`-based `number`** in the replacement string:

  - Including `(...)`, a parenthesized subexpression, in the regex implicitly creates a **capture group** (capturing group). By default, such capture groups are *unnamed* and must be referenced by their **`1`-based (decimal) *index* reflecting the order in which they appear in the regex**, so that `$1` refers to what the 1st group in your regex captured, `$2` to what the 2nd captured, ...
  - The form `${number}` (e.g., `${1}`) for *disambiguation* of the number is also supported (e.g., to make sure that `$1` is recognized even if followed by, say, `000`, use `${1}000`).
  - Instead of relying on *indices* to refer to unnamed capture groups, you can *name* capture groups and refer to them by name - see next point.
  - If you're not interested in what the capture group matched, you can opt to ignore it by turning it into a non-capturing group with `(?:...)`.
- `${name}` ... Includes the last substring matched by the ***named* capture group** that is designated by `(?<name>...)` in the replacement string.
- `$$` ... Includes a single **`"$"` literal** in the replacement string.
- `$&` ... Includes a copy of the **entire match** in the replacement string (`$0` works too, even though it [isn't *directly* documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-the-entire-match)).
- `` $` `` ... Includes the text of the **input string *before* the match** in the replacement string.
- `$'` ... Includes the text of the **input string *after* the match** in the replacement string.
- `$+` ... Includes the ***last* group captured** in the replacement string. [This relieves you of the need to know the last group's specific index.]
- `$_` ... Includes the **entire *input*** string in the replacement string.

Finally, note that:

- **`-replace` invariably matches *globally***, so if the input string contains *multiple* matches, the replacements above apply to *each* match.
- It is **generally preferable to use `'...'` (*single* quotes)** for both the regex and the replacement string, because single-quoted strings are non-expanding (non-interpolating), and therefore avoid confusion with PowerShell's own up-front expansions of `$`-prefixed tokens and interpretation of `` ` `` chars.
  If you do need to include PowerShell variables or expressions, you have three options:

  - Use `"..."` (expandable strings) and `` ` ``-escape `$` instances that are meant for the *regex engine*; e.g.,  `` `$1 `` in the following example:
    `` 'abc' -replace '(a)', "[`$1]-$HOME-" ``
    which yields something like `[a]-C:\Users\jdoe-bc`
  - Build your string from literal pieces and variable references using string concatenation (`+`); e.g.:
    `'abc' -replace '(a)', ('[$1]-' + $HOME + '-')`
  - Use `-f`, the string-formatting operator string concatenation; e.g.:
    `'abc' -replace '(a)', ('[$1]-{0}-' -f $HOME)`
- Given that you need to **use `$$` to escape a literal `$` in the *replacement* string**, use the following idiom to use a *variable* whose value you want to use *literally*:

  - `... -replace <search>, $var.Replace('$', '$$')`
  - This relies on the [`[string]::Replace()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) performing *literal substring* replacements.
    On a side note, this method is an alternative to `-replace` in simple cases, but note that it is case-*sensitive* by default.
  - Alternatively, use a *nested* `-replace` operation, but the syntax is tricky due to the escaping requirements:
    `... -replace <search>, ($var -replace '\$', '$$$$')`

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend regex101.com for learning regex.

Something like this can work:

```
"VideoName_s01e01.mp4" -replace '(.*s)(\d+)(e.*)', '$1$2_$3'
```

Gives:

```
VideoName_s01_e01.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

`-replace` is using  [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), not [wildcards](/questions/tagged/wildcards). Thus you have to change the replace to:

```
-replace '_s([0-9]{1,2})e([0-9]{1,2})', '_s$1_e$2_'
```

Answer (score 1):

regex is the better solution, i propose other with formating number and use Template

```
$exampleoffile = @"
namev1_s01e01.mp4
namvev2_s03e02.mp4
VideoName_s20e15.mp4
VideoName_s15e1.mp4
VideoName_s1e16.avi
VideoName_s1e23.mv
"@

$template=@"
{file*:{prefix:Test1}_s{season:01}e{episode:01}{extension:.mp4}}
{file*:{prefix:1xxx}_s{season:100}e{episode:5}{extension:.mp4}}
{file*:{prefix:yyy3}_s{season:10}e{episode:02}{extension:.havi}}
"@



$exampleoffile | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | 
% { "{0}_{1:D2}_e{2:D2}{3}" -f $_.file.prefix, [int]$_.file.season, [int]$_.file.episode, $_.file.extension }
```